# how can I display data in my listview into my homescreen widget?

Tags: android, listview, widget

I have a listview in my main activity  and I just want to display its data in my homescreen widget .Any tutorial or website if you know then please provide  I searched whole internet but failed to get what I want .
all I want is to  display listview in widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a `ListView` to your RemoteViews widget layout.
- You need to create a service - `RemoteViewService` and a `RemoteViewFactory` which will act as your adapter.
- You then need to call `setRemoteAdapter()` to populate the list.

There is a repository on `Github` which does exactly the same and was very handy for me. It is by CommonsGuy : [LoremWidget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget)